# iphone xml binding / parsing to objects

Tags: objective-c, ios, xml, cocoa-touch

I'm new to iphone developing and what I want is an xml parser that I can bind to Objects. I searched a lot but I still need some help. For example I have the following xml structure:

```
<xml>
  <hotels>
    <hotel>
      <id>1</id>
      <name>Hotel Name</name>
    </hotel>
    <hotel>
       ....
    </hotel>
  </hotels>
  <beaches>
    <beach>
      <id>11</id>
      <name>Beach Name</name>
    </beach>
    <beach>
       ....
    </beach>
  </beaches>
</xml>
```

Now my question is...which is the best (or maybe easier) way to read this xml file and parse for example...:

1. Now I want a list of all hotels...so I want o parse  and get that list...etc.
2. Now I want beach with id = 11 etc.

Can this be done easily in iphone? Which is the best approach? I would be thankful if you could give me examples with source code or such. Thanks in advance.

NOTE: I will support at least ios 4.3 or later.

Answer (score 1):

you can try implementing NSXMLParserDelegate then write your logic in

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI: 
(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary 
*)attributeDict

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:
(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
```

Example code:-

Create XMLParser class, then bean classes for Hotel, Beach and arrays for storing these objects.

XMLParser.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface XMLParser : NSObject <NSXMLParserDelegate>

@property (strong, readonly) NSMutableArray *yourObjects;

-(id) parseXML:(NSString *)url;

@end
```

XMLParser.m

```
#import "XMLParser.h"
#import "YourObject.h"
@implementation XMLParser

@synthesize yourObjects    =_yourObjects;

NSMutableString *currentNode;
NSXMLParser *parser;
YourObject *YourObject;

-(id) parseXML:(NSString *)url
{
       _yourObjects       = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
       NSURL *nsURL    = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
       NSData *data    = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:nsURL];
       parser          = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:data];
       parser.delegate = self;
       [parser parse];
       return self;
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
   currentNode = (NSMutableString *) [string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:       
   [NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:
(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary   
*)attributeDict

{
  if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"hotel"])
  {
    yourObject = [YourObject alloc]; //eg:- Hotel
    //any logic that you want to include.....
  }
  if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"beach"])
  {
    yourObject = [YourObject alloc]; //eg:- beach
    //any logic that you want to include.....
  }
}

@end

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI: 
(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{

   if([elementName isEqualToString:@"status"])
   {
     [self.yourObjects addObject:yourObject];
     yourObject = nil;
     currentNode  = nil;
    }
}
```

call   -(id) parseXML:(NSString *)url; to parse the required XML and retrieve the Objects.

Hope this helps.